# WooCommerce - Is is possible to replace downloadable file and allow existing customer to get it?

Tags: plugins

I have a WooWommerce 2.0 shop where I sell downloadables and, from time to time, I have to replace existing files with newer versions. When I replace the file URLs for the downloadable files, Customers who already purchased them earlier cannot get the latest version by following the link they received with their order, receiving a "No File Defined" error instead.

Is there a way to ensure that the link received with an order always grants access to all the files defined for the Downloadable Product, no matter what they are? Alternatively, would there be a way to send updated links to existing Customers?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever the actual file is, you should be able to FTP to it and simply replace it with a file with the exact same name. Unless Woocommerce keeps some kind of filesize account of what is there, it shouldn't know the difference as to whether it is delivering the old file or the new file.

Comment: That's the thing, files are not just linked to a URL. Besides, there can be multiple versions of a file, with different names, which is what causes the issue. I found the answer to my own question, though: one link = one file. If file changes, link changes and there is no "relationship" between the two. In short, it doesn't work the way I was thinking, I have to review my approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the **downloadable line items** where you can also grant access to new downloads.

[image: Screenshot of site info]

that screenshot it taken from 
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/digitaldownloadable-product-handling/

Comment: I saw that part, but I don't think it's what I need. The issue is that, originally, product pointed to a file named **myfile-1.2zip**; now I removed such file, as it's obsolete, and replaced it with **myfile-1.5zip**. Therefore, the URL for the downloadable product is now a different one, and existing Customers cannot download it.

Comment: By the way, in the **Downloadable Product Permissions** section, I see **#825 - MyFile v 1.5 - File: myfile-1.5.zip**, which means that the file is the correct one. However, people who originally got the link for v 1.2 cannot download 1.5 and get a "no file defined" error.